# Flutter get future list data into normal list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to show a list of items in a DropdownField, which requires a **non-future** list.

So I am trying to turn my future list (which I get from a database call) into a normal list by iterating over it and adding it to a new, normal, list, like so;
[image]
[image]

When I print the individual elements of the future list, I get results back.

[image]

But afterwards, when I print the new list, it returns as a null value.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can solve this issue ?

PS: I am **NOT** interested in a FutureBuilder solution. I know that I can show a future list with a futurebuilder, but this will not fit the solution I am hoping to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future reference, you might want to paste your actual code into the question so people can easily copy it into their answers. Otherwise, we have to write it out ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not initializing `newList`. You are trying to add items to a null list. Change the fourth line of `getAll()` to the following:

`var newList = List<dynamic>();`

You are also not `await`ing your firebase call. This means that you will print the array BEFORE you finish your firebase call. You need to make this `getAll()` method `async` and `await`, the firebase call so it doesn't print the null version.

Comment: Problem remains the same unfortunately - the list doesnt get new values added to it.

Comment: @lvb I updated my answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

That’s because you’re not waiting for the future to complete. When you do print(newList) the future isn’t completed yet.

You will have to need to await the getAnswers data to archieve what you want.

```dart
final answers = await getAnswersList();
for (final answer in answers) {
  print(answer.toString());
}
```